# Drawing PolyLine Using an Array of LatLng Coordinates in Google Maps API V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I was trying to draw a dynamic polyline in Javascript using Google Map API v3, Here is the Code snippet which i am using :

```
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
var myTrip=new Array();
//var y=new google.maps.LatLng(28.360012,77.031527);
//var z=new google.maps.LatLng(28.360124,77.031429);
myTrip.push(new google.maps.LatLng(28.360012,77.031527));
myTrip.push(new google.maps.LatLng(28.360124,77.031429));
myTrip.push(new google.maps.LatLng(28.361024,77.034129));
var flightPath=new google.maps.Polyline({
path:myTrip,
strokeColor:"#0000FF",
strokeOpacity:0.8,
strokeWeight:2
});
flightPath.setMap(map); 
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

This isn't drawing Polyline on the map.

Can someone please help me with this ?

Comment: Your code works fine but is incomplete. Is the variable holding your map really called `map`? Btw. you don't need the single quotes around the coordinates. For example: `new google.maps.LatLng(28.360012,77.031527)`

Comment: Yes the variable holding map is 'map', i removed the quotes, yet it isn't working fine. i have made the changes in the code

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you getting any error in the browser javascript console?

Comment: the polyline isn't shown on the browser

Comment: My code is embedded inside an HTML Code and i am viewing the map on the browser.

Comment: Please check: http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/K8v6X/ It is a copy of the code above and it works fine.

Comment: Where's your `initialize` function?  See @MrUpsidown's example which wraps most of your code in just such a function... you don't have one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing an `initialize` function:

```
function initialize() {
    var mapProp = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(28.360012, 77.031527),
        zoom: 18,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
    var myTrip=new Array();
    myTrip.push(new google.maps.LatLng(28.360012,77.031527));
    myTrip.push(new google.maps.LatLng(28.360124,77.031429));
    myTrip.push(new google.maps.LatLng(28.361024,77.034129));
    var flightPath=new google.maps.Polyline({
        path:myTrip,
        strokeColor:"#0000FF",
        strokeOpacity:0.8,
        strokeWeight:2
    });
    flightPath.setMap(map); 
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```